# Debian 10 "repository does not have a release"

Tags: debian

Let me start off by saying I'm relatively new to Linux. My environment is a Debian 10 VM running a Graylog logging service. In an attempt to update Graylog(`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade`), I get the following results:
[image: Error]

(I'm sorry I can't directly copy and paste the results, I'm basically in a nested remote desktop due to Covid)
I've looked around and have found solutions to similar problems, but found it difficult to understand them. Moreover, none of them had a 404 error.

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian Buster does not look like it has any staging versions of the backports repo, or at least not anymore.

Import fasttrack archive keyring (if you do not have it already):

```
apt -t buster-backports install fasttrack-archive-keyring
```

Add/edit the following lines to /etc/apt/sources.list on your buster system.

```
deb https://fasttrack.debian.net/debian/ buster-fasttrack main contrib

deb https://fasttrack.debian.net/debian/ buster-backports main contrib
```

and delete the old ones, which contain `buster-fasttrack-staging`

And then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: The `fasttrack-staging` is only available for Bullseye.

Comment: Ah ok thank you both for the clarification! I mustve installed the wrong version somewhere along the way.